# How to get swagger-ui for wordnik/swagger-core sample java-jaxrs

Tags: servlets, web.xml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am new to swagger world. I downloaded the wordnki/swagger-core from github and deployed java-jaxrs sample. The url http:localhost:8080/api/api-docs/pet returns the response. I want to view this content in swagger-ui.

I added the swagger-ui directory contains needed js and html files. How to configure my web.xml to view this swagger-ui? so that I can configure my resource in swagger url as http:localhost:8002/api/api-docs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following mapping in your web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DEFAULT_REST_SERVLET</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>{{your_dispatcher_servlet}}</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DEFAULT_REST_SERVLET</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/v1/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/api-docs/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

hope this helps